# Control on which monitor application starts

Tags: powershell, monitors

I have an computer which runs monitoring application and has 6 monitors  displaying various applications monitoring multiple systems. When this computer is restarted (which happens pretty regularly) someone always has to logon to the computer and reposition the application it is running. 
Is there a way to start an application on a specific monitor with powershell? Best would be if it is possible to start a application on screen n. 2 f.e. and in maximized mode.

Answer (score 0):

Another module needs to be downloaded, but this seems to handle what you're looking for.

https://superuser.com/questions/769575/set-many-programs-window-size-position